# How can I create two separate buttons with two separate inputs in Plotly Dash?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

What I need is simple.

One button that prints "A".

Another, SEPARATE button that prints "B".

Both Buttons are in no way are related.

How do I do this in plotly dash by using two separate callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Built this minimal example.  I have found a **callback** requires an **Output**
- have used straight forward **Div** to meet this requirement

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Button("Button A", id="button-a", n_clicks=0),
        html.Button("Button B", id="button-b", n_clicks=0),
        html.Div(id="out-a"),
        html.Div(id="out-b"),
    ],
)

@app.callback(
    Output("out-a", "children"),
    Input("button-a", "n_clicks"),
)
def buttonA(nClicks):
    print("button A")
    return None

@app.callback(
    Output("out-b", "children"),
    Input("button-b", "n_clicks"),
)
def buttonB(nClicks):
    print("button B")
    return None



# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode="inline")
```